# Compress an InputStream with gzip

Tags: java, gzip

I would like to compress an input stream in java using Gzip compression.

Let's say we have an input stream (1GB of data..) not compressed. I want as a result a compressed inputstream from the source :

```
public InputStream getCompressedStream(InputStream unCompressedStream) {

    // Not working because it's uncompressing the stream, I want the opposite.
    return new GZIPInputStream(unCompressedStream); 

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DeflaterInputStream is not what you want because it lacks gzip header/trailer and uses a slightly different compression.

If you change from OutputStream (push) to InputStream (pull) you need to do things different.

What GzipOutputStream does is:

- write a static gzip header
- write a deflated stream using DeflaterOutputStream. While the stream is written, a CRC32 checksum is built from the uncompressed data and the number of bytes is count
- write a trailer containing the CRC32 Checksum and the number of bytes.

If you want to do the same with InputStreams, you need a stream that contains:

- the header
- the deflated content
- the trailer

The best way to do this is to provide 3 different streams and combine them to one. Fortunately there is SequenceInputStream that does the combining of the streams for you.

Here's my implementation plus a simple unit test:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterInputStream;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;

/**
 * @author mwyraz
 * Wraps an input stream and compresses it's contents. Similiar to DeflateInputStream but adds GZIP-header and trailer
 * See GzipOutputStream for details.
 * LICENSE: Free to use. Contains some lines from GzipOutputStream, so oracle's license might apply as well!
 */
public class GzipCompressingInputStream extends SequenceInputStream
{
    public GzipCompressingInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        this(in,512);
    }
    public GzipCompressingInputStream(InputStream in, int bufferSize) throws IOException
    {
        super(new StatefullGzipStreamEnumerator(in,bufferSize));
    }

    static enum StreamState
    {
        HEADER,
        CONTENT,
        TRAILER
    }

    protected static class StatefullGzipStreamEnumerator implements Enumeration<InputStream>
    {

        protected final InputStream in;
        protected final int bufferSize;
        protected StreamState state;

        public StatefullGzipStreamEnumerator(InputStream in, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.in=in;
            this.bufferSize=bufferSize;
            state=StreamState.HEADER;
        }

        public boolean hasMoreElements()
        {
            return state!=null;
        }
        public InputStream nextElement()
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case HEADER:
                    state=StreamState.CONTENT;
                    return createHeaderStream();
                case CONTENT:
                    state=StreamState.TRAILER;
                    return createContentStream();
                case TRAILER:
                    state=null;
                    return createTrailerStream();
            }
            return null;
        }

        static final int GZIP_MAGIC = 0x8b1f;
        static final byte[] GZIP_HEADER=new byte[] {
                (byte) GZIP_MAGIC,        // Magic number (short)
                (byte)(GZIP_MAGIC >> 8),  // Magic number (short)
                Deflater.DEFLATED,        // Compression method (CM)
                0,                        // Flags (FLG)
                0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                0,                        // Extra flags (XFLG)
                0                         // Operating system (OS)
        };
        protected InputStream createHeaderStream()
        {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(GZIP_HEADER);
        }
        protected InternalGzipCompressingInputStream contentStream;
        protected InputStream createContentStream()
        {
            contentStream=new InternalGzipCompressingInputStream(new CRC32InputStream(in), bufferSize);
            return contentStream;
        }
        protected InputStream createTrailerStream()
        {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(contentStream.createTrailer());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal stream without header/trailer  
     */
    protected static class CRC32InputStream extends FilterInputStream
    {
        protected CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        protected long byteCount;
        public CRC32InputStream(InputStream in)
        {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException
        {
            int val=super.read();
            if (val>=0)
            {
                crc.update(val);
                byteCount++;
            }
            return val;
        }
        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
        {
            len=super.read(b, off, len);
            if (len>=0)
            {
                crc.update(b,off,len);
                byteCount+=len;
            }
            return len;
        }
        public long getCrcValue()
        {
            return crc.getValue();
        }
        public long getByteCount()
        {
            return byteCount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal stream without header/trailer  
     */
    protected static class InternalGzipCompressingInputStream extends DeflaterInputStream
    {
        protected final CRC32InputStream crcIn;
        public InternalGzipCompressingInputStream(CRC32InputStream in, int bufferSize)
        {
            super(in, new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true),bufferSize);
            crcIn=in;
        }
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            if (in != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    def.end();
                    in.close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    in = null;
                }
            }
        }

        protected final static int TRAILER_SIZE = 8;

        public byte[] createTrailer()
        {
            byte[] trailer= new byte[TRAILER_SIZE];
            writeTrailer(trailer, 0);
            return trailer;
        }

        /*
         * Writes GZIP member trailer to a byte array, starting at a given
         * offset.
         */
        private void writeTrailer(byte[] buf, int offset)
        {
            writeInt((int)crcIn.getCrcValue(), buf, offset); // CRC-32 of uncompr. data
            writeInt((int)crcIn.getByteCount(), buf, offset + 4); // Number of uncompr. bytes
        }

        /*
         * Writes integer in Intel byte order to a byte array, starting at a
         * given offset.
         */
        private void writeInt(int i, byte[] buf, int offset)
        {
            writeShort(i & 0xffff, buf, offset);
            writeShort((i >> 16) & 0xffff, buf, offset + 2);
        }

        /*
         * Writes short integer in Intel byte order to a byte array, starting
         * at a given offset
         */
        private void writeShort(int s, byte[] buf, int offset)
        {
            buf[offset] = (byte)(s & 0xff);
            buf[offset + 1] = (byte)((s >> 8) & 0xff);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestGzipCompressingInputStream
{

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        testCompressor("test1 test2 test3");
        testCompressor("1MB binary data",createTestPattern(1024*1024));
        for (int i=0;i<4096;i++)
        {
            testCompressor(i+" bytes of binary data",createTestPattern(i));
        }
    }

    protected byte[] createTestPattern(int size)
    {
        byte[] data=new byte[size];
        byte pattern=0;
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            data[i]=pattern++;
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected void testCompressor(String data) throws IOException
    {
        testCompressor("String: "+data,data.getBytes());
    }
    protected void testCompressor(String dataInfo, byte[] data) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream uncompressedIn=new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        InputStream compressedIn=new GzipCompressingInputStream(uncompressedIn);
        InputStream uncompressedOut=new GZIPInputStream(compressedIn);

        byte[] result=StreamHelper.readBinaryStream(uncompressedOut);

        assertTrue("Test failed for: "+dataInfo,Arrays.equals(data,result));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this awe some response! When do I need to decompress the inputstream by converting the class to GZIPinputStream? Currently I'm taking in an inputStream from docker but instead I want to use you class to download an image immediately into a compressing stream that you made. Then I want to upload that compressed stream to AWS S3 to be used by other microservices. I should use the GZIPinputStream decompressing class when downloading and interacting with the input stream from the other microservices correct? Is the only time I can keep an input stream compressed in transit?

Comment: Also you forgot to include the class and function for the helper method you used: StreamHelper.readBinaryStream

Comment: Also why do we compress on input when there is already the GZipOutputStream that already compresses for us?

Comment: you can use this instead of the missing helper function btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version that I wrote that doesn't have the CRC/GZIP Magic cookies in it, because it delegates to a GZIPOutputStream. It is also memory efficient in that it only uses enough memory to buffer the compression (a 42MB file used a 45k buffer). Performance is the same as compressing to memory.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

/**
 * Compresses an InputStream in a memory-optimal, on-demand way only compressing enough to fill a buffer.
 * 
 * @author Ben La Monica
 */
public class GZIPCompressingInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream in;
    private GZIPOutputStream gz;
    private OutputStream delegate;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    private byte[] readBuf = new byte[8192];
    int read = 0;
    int write = 0;

    public GZIPCompressingInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        this.in = in;
        this.delegate = new OutputStream() {

            private void growBufferIfNeeded(int len) {
                if ((write + len) >= buf.length) {
                    // grow the array if we don't have enough space to fulfill the incoming data
                    byte[] newbuf = new byte[(buf.length + len) * 2];
                    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newbuf, 0, buf.length);
                    buf = newbuf;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                growBufferIfNeeded(len);
                System.arraycopy(b, off, buf, write, len);
                write += len;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                growBufferIfNeeded(1);
                buf[write++] = (byte) b;
            }
        };
        this.gz = new GZIPOutputStream(delegate); 
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        compressStream();
        int numBytes = Math.min(len, write-read);
        if (numBytes > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(buf, read, b, off, numBytes);
            read += numBytes;
        } else if (len > 0) {
            // if bytes were requested, but we have none, then we're at the end of the stream
            return -1;
        }
        return numBytes;
    }

    private void compressStream() throws IOException {
        // if the reader has caught up with the writer, then zero the positions out
        if (read == write) {
            read = 0;
            write = 0;
        }

        while (write == 0) {
            // feed the gzip stream data until it spits out a block
            int val = in.read(readBuf);
            if (val == -1) {
                // nothing left to do, we've hit the end of the stream. finalize and break out
                gz.close();
                break;
            } else if (val > 0) {
                gz.write(readBuf, 0, val);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        compressStream();
        if (write == 0) {
            // write should not be 0 if we were able to get data from compress stream, must mean we're at the end
            return -1;
        } else {
            // reading a single byte
            return buf[read++] & 0xFF;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! I found it useful to forward the close method to the delegate stream: `@Override public void close() throws IOException { in.close(); } `

Answer (score 4):

A working example of a compressing input stream can be found in the popular open source ESB [Mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_%28software%29): [`GZIPCompressorInputStream`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/98e3a382bc9698d0a9503be3ecfda7e94f64888a/core/src/main/java/org/mule/util/compression/GZIPCompressorInputStream.java).

It uses the [`DeflaterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterInputStream.html) provided by the JRE for compression, prepends the [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) header and appends the gzip trailer (aka footer).

Unfortunately, it is under [CPA License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Public_Attribution_License), which does not seem to be very common.
In addition, there seems to be no unit test.

Comment: Apache Commons Compress now has [GzipCompressorInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.12/index.html)

Comment: @user1585916: The Apache commons implementation has the same name, however **it does not compress** - from the JavaDoc: `Input stream that decompresses .gz files.`

Comment: What an awful name for a class @Apache

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to load content into large byte array and need true streaming solution :

```
package x.y.z;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

/**
 * Stream Compression Utility
 *
 * @author Thamme Gowda N
 */
public enum CompressionUtil {
    INSTANCE;

    public static final int NUM_THREADS = 5;
    private final ExecutorService pool;

    CompressionUtil(){
        this.pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    }

    public static CompressionUtil getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Supported compression type names
     */
    public static enum CompressionType {
        GZIP,
        ZIP
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the given stream in a Compressor stream based on given type
     * @param sourceStream : Stream to be wrapped
     * @param type         : Compression type
     * @return source stream wrapped in a compressor stream
     * @throws IOException when some thing bad happens
     */
    public static OutputStream getCompressionWrapper(OutputStream sourceStream,
                                     CompressionType type) throws IOException {

        switch (type) {
            case GZIP:
                return new GZIPOutputStream(sourceStream);
            case ZIP:
                return new ZipOutputStream(sourceStream);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Possible values :"
                        + Arrays.toString(CompressionType.values()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets Compressed Stream for given input Stream
     * @param sourceStream  : Input Stream to be compressed to
     * @param type: Compression types such as GZIP
     * @return  Compressed Stream
     * @throws IOException when some thing bad happens
     */
    public static InputStream getCompressedStream(final InputStream sourceStream,
                                    CompressionType type ) throws IOException {

        if(sourceStream == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source Stream cannot be NULL");
        }

        /**
         *  sourceStream --> zipperOutStream(->intermediateStream -)--> resultStream
         */
        final PipedInputStream resultStream = new PipedInputStream();
        final PipedOutputStream intermediateStream = new PipedOutputStream(resultStream);
        final OutputStream zipperOutStream = getCompressionWrapper(intermediateStream, type);

        Runnable copyTask = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int c;
                    while((c = sourceStream.read()) >= 0) {
                        zipperOutStream.write(c);
                    }
                    zipperOutStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(resultStream);  // close it on error case only
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    // close source stream and intermediate streams
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(sourceStream);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(zipperOutStream);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(intermediateStream);
                }
            }
        };
        getInstance().pool.submit(copyTask);
        return resultStream;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = "abcdefghij";
        InputStream sourceStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        InputStream compressedStream =
                getCompressedStream(sourceStream, CompressionType.GZIP);

        GZIPInputStream decompressedStream = new GZIPInputStream(compressedStream);
        List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(decompressedStream);
        String output = lines.get(0);
        System.out.println("test passed ? " + input.equals(output));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems I was late for 3 years, but maybe will be useful for someone.
My solution is similar to @Michael Wyraz's solution, only difference is that my solution is based on `FilterInputStream`

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

public class GZipInputStreamDeflater extends FilterInputStream {

    private static enum Stage {
        HEADER,
        DATA,
        FINALIZATION,
        TRAILER,
        FINISH
    }

    private GZipInputStreamDeflater.Stage stage = Stage.HEADER;

    private final Deflater deflater = new Deflater( Deflater.DEFLATED, true );
    private final CRC32 crc = new CRC32();

    /* GZIP header magic number */
    private final static int GZIP_MAGIC = 0x8b1f;

    private ByteArrayInputStream trailer = null;
    private ByteArrayInputStream header = new ByteArrayInputStream( new byte[] {
        (byte) GZIP_MAGIC, // Magic number (short)
        (byte) ( GZIP_MAGIC >> 8 ), // Magic number (short)
        Deflater.DEFLATED, // Compression method (CM)
        0, // Flags (FLG)
        0, // Modification time MTIME (int)
        0, // Modification time MTIME (int)
        0, // Modification time MTIME (int)
        0, // Modification time MTIME (int)
        0, // Extra flags (XFLG)
        0, // Operating system (OS)
    } );

    public GZipInputStreamDeflater(InputStream in) {
        super( in );
        crc.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int read( byte[] b, int off, int len ) throws IOException {
        int read = -1;

        switch( stage ) {
            case FINISH:
                return -1;
            case HEADER:
                read = header.read( b, off, len );
                if( header.available() == 0 ) {
                    stage = Stage.DATA;
                }
                return read;
            case DATA:
                byte[] b2 = new byte[len];
                read = super.read( b2, 0, len );
                if( read <= 0 ) {
                    stage = Stage.FINALIZATION;
                    deflater.finish();
                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                    deflater.setInput( b2, 0, read );
                    crc.update( b2, 0, read );
                    read = 0;
                    while( !deflater.needsInput() && len - read > 0 ) {
                        read += deflater.deflate( b, off + read, len - read, Deflater.NO_FLUSH );
                    }
                    return read;
                }
            case FINALIZATION:
                if( deflater.finished() ) {
                    stage = Stage.TRAILER;

                    int crcVaue = (int) crc.getValue();
                    int totalIn = deflater.getTotalIn();

                    trailer = new ByteArrayInputStream( new byte[] {
                        (byte) ( crcVaue >> 0 ),
                        (byte) ( crcVaue >> 8 ),
                        (byte) ( crcVaue >> 16 ),
                        (byte) ( crcVaue >> 24 ),

                        (byte) ( totalIn >> 0 ),
                        (byte) ( totalIn >> 8 ),
                        (byte) ( totalIn >> 16 ),
                        (byte) ( totalIn >> 24 ),
                    } );

                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                    read = deflater.deflate( b, off, len, Deflater.FULL_FLUSH );
                    return read;
                }
            case TRAILER:
                read = trailer.read( b, off, len );
                if( trailer.available() == 0 ) {
                    stage = Stage.FINISH;
                }
                return read;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void close( ) throws IOException {
        super.close();
        deflater.end();
        if( trailer != null ) {
            trailer.close();
        }
        header.close();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client( ... );
try ( InputStream in = new GZipInputStreamDeflater( new URL( "http://....../very-big-file.csv" ).openStream() ); ) {
    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest( "BUCKET-NAME", "/object/key", in, new ObjectMetadata() );
    s3client.putObject( putRequest );
}
```

Comment: Nicolai have you considered publishing this as a library?

Comment: Thank you, @JoshLemer. I didn't thought about publishing this as a library. Do you think that it would be a useful library? It contains a single class only and is very small for library, isn't it?

Comment: Keep in mind that are not supplying S3 with `Content-Length` meta data as part of `PutObjectRequest` and it will cause S3 SDK to internally buffer entire stream in order to discover the length which will cause OutOfMemoryError in case of large uploads as you may run over the memory limit. It would be safer to initiate a multipart upload instead using [InitiateMultipartUploadRequest](https://amzn.to/2sMnNss) then [UploadPartRequest](https://amzn.to/2sTG0U4) and finally [CompleteMultipartUploadRequest](https://amzn.to/2sJ1T9B).

Comment: Fittingly another three years late, I fear there is a bug in this. In the `DATA` state, the `deflater` may have more data to return that the read buffer can accommodate. However, the next read will overwrite this data on the first `defalter.setInput`.

The fix is to ensure we only set more input data when the deflater is exhausted. A Kotlin variant with this fix can be found in [http4k](https://github.com/http4k/http4k/blob/5026d010f1842ee784199cbd9cd6efe8608524d5/http4k-core/src/main/kotlin/org/http4k/filter/ext.kt#L72) if interested.

Answer (score 3):

[PipedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) lets you write to a GZIPOutputStream and expose that data through an InputStream. It has a fixed memory cost, unlike other solutions which buffer the entire stream of data to an array or file. Only problem is you can't read and write from the same Thread, you have to use a separate one.

```
private InputStream gzipInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    PipedInputStream zipped = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream pipe = new PipedOutputStream(zipped);
    new Thread(
            () -> {
                try(OutputStream zipper = new GZIPOutputStream(pipe)){
                    IOUtils.copy(in, zipper);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    ).start();
    return zipped;
}
```

Comment: A nice solution. The only thing that gives me a headache is how to get the potential `IOException` out of the thread so that it is not ignored.

Comment: I think at that point I'd reach for [EasyStream's OutputStreamToInputStream](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/apidocs/com/gc/iotools/stream/os/OutputStreamToInputStream.html) as @smartwjw suggests in his answer. It does essentially this under the hood, but the documentation says it exposes any exceptions through [getResult()](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/apidocs/com/gc/iotools/stream/os/OutputStreamToInputStream.html#getResult--)

Comment: As a comment, having tried this and had it simply not work, do not try to put the `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` declarations in a try-with-resources declaration, e.g.
`try (InputStream is = ... ; //whatever to open the input stream PipedInputStream zipped = new PipedInputStream(); PipedOutputStream pipe = new PipedOutputStream(zipped);) { new Thread(....) //as above` - it fails!  If you want to do that, put the opening of `in` above in the try-with-resources declaration and the rest in the try block

Answer (score 2):

To compress data you need the `GZIPOutputStream`. But since you need to read the data back as if from an InputStream you need to convert the OutputStream to an InputStream. You can use getBytes() to do so:

```
GZIPOutputStream gout = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
//... Code to read from your original uncompressed data and write to out.

//Convert to InputStream.
new ByteArrayInputStream(gout.getBytes());
```

But this method has the limitation that you need to read in all data first - and that means you have to have enough memory to hold that buffer.

Alternative approaches using Pipes are mentioned in this thread - [How to convert OutputStream to InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/java-converting-from-outputstream-to-inputstream)

Comment: @Fabien - read your comment below - if you do have 1TB data to read from the input stream - dont use above method !! Unless you have 1TB memory to spare ofcourse. Use the pipe methods.

Comment: There is no "good" standard way to make an OutputStream be an InputStream. There are only 2 ways to do so. Either cache the whole OutputSTream somewhere or to use threads. Both have their disadvantages. Use an InputStream if you can. See my post below.

Comment: @kjp - GZIPOutputStream does not have a default constructor.

Comment: Please update the answer, not sure it was valid in 2012, but I know it is not valid in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `DeflatingGZIPInputStream` in the JRE. To deflate with the "deflate" compression format, use `java.util.zip.DeflaterInputStream` and `java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream`:

```
public InputStream getCompressedStream(InputStream unCompressedStream) {
    return new DeflaterInputStream(unCompressedStream); 
}
```

You could derive a class from `java.util.zip.DeflaterInputStream` that deflates in GZIP format by looking at the the source of `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be looking at `GZIPOutputStream` in that case?

```
public OutputStream getCompressedStream(InputStream input) {
    OutputStream output = new GZIPOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()); 
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: GZIPOutputStream return an OutputStream. But I want an InputStream.

Comment: You can't create an input from an input. You can only create an output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EasyStream](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/easystream/).

```
try(final InputStreamFromOutputStream<Void> isOs = new InputStreamFromOutputStream<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected void produce(final OutputStream dataSink) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(unCompressedStream);
        IOUtils.copy(in, dataSink);
    }
}) {        

    //You can use the compressed input stream here

} catch (final IOException e) {
    //Handle exceptions here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public InputStream getCompressed( InputStream is ) throws IOException
{
    byte data[] = new byte[2048];
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GzipOutputStream zos = new GzipOutputStream( bos );
    BufferedInputStream entryStream = new BufferedInputStream( is, 2048);
    int count;
    while ( ( count = entryStream.read( data, 0, 2048) ) != -1 )
    {
        zos.write( data, 0, count );
    }
    entryStream.close();
    zos.close();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream( bos.toByteArray() );
}
```

ref :[zip compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221128/convert-zipoutputstream-to-bytearrayinputstream?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend using [GzipCompressorInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/gzip/GzipCompressorInputStream.html) from [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/).

Comment: GzipCompressorInputStream decompresses like the JRE GZIPInputStream does.