# Convert ZipOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: compression, zipoutputstream

I want to compress an `InputStream` using `ZipOutputStream` and then get the `InputStream` from compressed `ZipOutputStream` without saving file on disc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
public InputStream getCompressed(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(""));

    int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[2048];
    BufferedInputStream entryStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 2048);
    while ((count = entryStream.read(data, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
        zos.write( data, 0, count );
    }
    entryStream.close();

    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Came here to see if my code would work and found that I did just the same as you