# Spring REST - create ZIP file and send it to the client

Tags: java, spring, rest, zip, zipoutputstream

I want to create a ZIP file that contains my archived files that I received from the backend, and then send this file to a user. For 2 days I have been looking for the answer and can't find proper solution, maybe you can help me :)

**For now, the code is like this** (I know I shouldn't do it all in the Spring controller, but don't care about that, it is just for testing purposes, to find the way to make it works):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/zip")
    public byte[] zipFiles(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Setting HTTP headers
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");

        // Creating byteArray stream, make it bufferable and passing this buffer to ZipOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

        // Simple file list, just for tests
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(2);
        files.add(new File("README.md"));

        // Packing files
        for (File file : files) {
            // New zip entry and copying InputStream with file to ZipOutputStream, after all closing streams
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

            fileInputStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        if (zipOutputStream != null) {
            zipOutputStream.finish();
            zipOutputStream.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(zipOutputStream);
        }
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedOutputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(byteArrayOutputStream);

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

But the problem is, that using the code, when I enter the URL `localhost:8080/zip`, I get a file `test.zip.html` instead of `.zip` file.

When I remove `.html` extension and leave just `test.zip` it opens correctly. So my questions are:

- How to avoid returning this `.html` extension?
- Why is it added?

---

I have no idea what else can I do. I was also trying replace `ByteArrayOuputStream` with something like:

```
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

and set the method to be **void** so it returns nothing, but It created `.zip` file which was damaged?

On my MacBook after unpacking the `test.zip` I was getting `test.zip.cpgz` which was again giving me `test.zip` file and so on.

On Windows the .zip file was damaged as I said and couldn't even open it.

I also suppose, that removing `.html` extension automatically will be the best option, but how?

Hope it is no as hard as It seems to be :)
Thanks

Comment: you might find the answer here helpful.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492465/3946706

Answer (score 45):

#### The problem is solved.

I replaced:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
```

with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/zip", produces="application/zip")
```

And now I get a clear, beautiful `.zip` file.

---

If any of you have either better or faster proposition, or just want to give some advice, then go ahead, I am curious.

Comment: +1 For non-trivial question and answering your own question! The only question / concern I have with this implementation is the final return statement. I think this would load the entire file into memory because of `toByteArray()`. Right? I wonder if there is a way to stream it to avoid some OutOfMemoryException errors if the directory is too large.

Comment: see this page if you need generic solution for any case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595252/15959923

Answer (score 43):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/zip", produces="application/zip")
public void zipFiles(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    //setting headers  
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");

    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    // create a list to add files to be zipped
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(2);
    files.add(new File("README.md"));

    // package files
    for (File file : files) {
        //new zip entry and copying inputstream with file to zipOutputStream, after all closing streams
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

        fileInputStream.close();
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    }    

    zipOutputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: because this solution streams data directly to response output stream.

Comment: This is java server side codes, how to download it in client by javascript??

Comment: @HarveyDent - yous should ask that as a new question.

Comment: Please, I was stuck into this problem for two whole days. thanks in advance

Comment: you just call the url.  in the code above it would be http://<host>/zip

Comment: see this page if you need generic solution for any case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595252/15959923

Answer (score 20):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/zip", produces="application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> zipFiles() {
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"")
            .body(out -> {
                var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);

                // create a list to add files to be zipped
                ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(2);
                files.add(new File("README.md"));

                // package files
                for (File file : files) {
                    //new zip entry and copying inputstream with file to zipOutputStream, after all closing streams
                    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);

                    fileInputStream.close();
                    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                }

                zipOutputStream.close();
            });
}
```

Comment: +1 for helping me figure out how to do this without creating a HttpServletResponse, since this doesn't seem to set a status code on 404s.

Comment: If there is a run time exception anywhere in the body block, will still return 200

Comment: Attaching a relevant post about trouble handling exception with StreamingResponseBody https://stackoverflow.com/q/65557527/5777189

Comment: see this page if you need generic solution for any case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595252/15959923

Answer (score 4):

I am using `REST Web Service` of `Spring Boot` and I have designed the endpoints to always return `ResponseEntity` whether it is `JSON` or `PDF` or `ZIP` and I came up with the following solution which is partially inspired by `denov's answer` in this question as well as another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221128/convert-zipoutputstream-to-bytearrayinputstream) where I learned how to convert `ZipOutputStream` into `byte[]` in order to feed it to `ResponseEntity` as output of the endpoint.

Anyway, I created a simple utility class with two methods for `pdf` and `zip` file download

```
@Component
public class FileUtil {
    public BinaryOutputWrapper prepDownloadAsPDF(String filename) throws IOException {
        Path fileLocation = Paths.get(filename);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String outputFilename = "output.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(outputFilename, outputFilename);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

        return new BinaryOutputWrapper(data, headers); 
    }

    public BinaryOutputWrapper prepDownloadAsZIP(List<String> filenames) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"));
        String outputFilename = "output.zip";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(outputFilename, outputFilename);
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteOutputStream);

        for(String filename: filenames) {
            File file = new File(filename); 
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));           
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);
            fileInputStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }           
        zipOutputStream.close();
        return new BinaryOutputWrapper(byteOutputStream.toByteArray(), headers); 
    }
}
```

And now the endpoint can easily return `ResponseEntity<?>` as shown below using the `byte[]` data and custom headers that is specifically tailored for `pdf` or `zip`.

```
@GetMapping("/somepath/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<?> generatePDF() {
    BinaryOutputWrapper output = new BinaryOutputWrapper(); 
    try {
        String inputFile = "sample.pdf"; 
        output = fileUtil.prepDownloadAsPDF(inputFile);
        //or invoke prepDownloadAsZIP(...) with a list of filenames
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Do something when exception is thrown
    } 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(output.getData(), output.getHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

The `BinaryOutputWrapper` is a simple immutable `POJO` class I created with `private byte[] data;` and `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers;` as fields in order to return both `data` and `headers` from utility method.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream stores the bytes in memory. So for large files you can run out of heap space very quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Only thing that worked for Spring Boot application
**(without any hardcoded file paths!)**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/zip-download", produces="application/zip")
public void zipDownload(@RequestParam List<String> name, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");

    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    for (String fileName : name) {

        // resource content length
        int contentLength = 123;
        // resource input stream
        InputStream stream = InputStream.nullInputStream();

        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zipEntry.setSize(contentLength);

        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        StreamUtils.copy(stream, zipOut);

        zipOut.closeEntry();
    }

    zipOut.finish();
    zipOut.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. The client gave the error invalid zip file.

Comment: @Saurabh probably because it was empty, that's common thing

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. Sorry about the down vote. I cannot change it now due to Stackoverflow restrictions. Thanks