# Spring MVC REST return JSON response as ZIP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Have the following Spring REST code which returns a JSON response-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewAllEmployees.do")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Employee> viewAllItems() {
        List<Employee> allEmployees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        return allEmployees;
    }
```

How can this be modified to return the JSON response as a zip? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to set "application/zip" as produces in request mapping.
This should treat it as header.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewAllEmployees.do", produces="application/zip")
public byte[] viewAllItems() {
...
```

You can check how to convert to zip:
[Spring REST - create .zip file and send it to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952949/spring-rest-create-zip-file-and-send-it-to-the-client)

Comment: Thanks chmielu..So the JSON data will be required to change to byte[] while returning response?

Comment: Yes. Try to check this link it might be the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952949/spring-rest-create-zip-file-and-send-it-to-the-client I would save the Json response in to tmp file and then fallow the steps in the link

Comment: Or you can put the JSON response into stream and copy to ZipOutputStream