# Using InputStream/OutputStream to handle data flows through modules

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, dataflow

so now I have a bunch of modules. It's like a assembly line. There is data flowing through and each module does something about the data, or you can say the next module consumes the output that the previous module produces. Each module is sort of expected to be standalone and reusable. This is quite a typical scenario I think.

So initially I have designed each module's interface as module(InputStream is, OutputStream os). So it can take files, whatever sources, as input and output. When you think of data flows, the previous module's outputstream is going to the next module's inputstream. But then I realise Java doesn't even have a intuitive/easy way to get data from OutputStream to InputStream. 
(Note: This question is not about how to achieve this. For those who is interested, 
[How to convert OutputStream to InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/java-converting-from-outputstream-to-inputstream))

It seems to me that probably OutputStream/InputStream is not meant for purpose like this.
So what is the best way to design the interface to handle data flows in this case?

Answer (score 1):

For discrete objects you can use a producer/consumer pattern with [ConcurrentLinkedQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [BlockingQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) - each module has its own queue, and it will continually `poll` its queue (or use `take` if it's a BlockingQueue), process the object, and `offer` it to the next module's queue.

This pattern can also work with a byte stream if you chunk it into smaller byte arrays that you pass through the queues, but this isn't always appropriate (e.g. if module1 reads, module2 compresses, and module3 encrypts, then you're probably better off keeping the data in streams, unless you have some reasonable way to chunk the data).

Comment: Yes, my case is very much like module1 parses, module2 compresses, and module3 encrypts.. Chunking data to make it fit in ConcurrentLinkedQueues or BlockingQueues pattern doesn't make sense. And it all happens in sequence. Simple as it is no concurrency involved.

Comment: I'll definitely hear and learn more about this but so far it appears to me that InputStream/OutputStream is badly designed. It'd have been a nice and clear way to handle data interface.

Comment: You may be able to solve this with the `copy` methods in [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), e.g. [copy inputstream to outputstream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a general module which implements the `OutputStream` to `InputStream` conversion and place one instance of the module between each of your other modules. You could even get fancy with it and make the module intelligent enough to route the messages from one module to any of the other modules. This would become a sort of gateway or router type module.

Alternatively, you could implement something a bit heavier weight with a message queuing and passing framework like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava).
--ap

Comment: Put the OutputStream to InputStream conversion as a utility class is the way I am doing it. But it doesn't change the fact that it is awkward and counter-intuitive. What I'm saying is if stream is the way to go, there would have been some elegant ways to do OutputStream/InputStream conversion, instead of all sorts of hacks. Even Apache IOUtils only implements copying from InputStream to OutputStream but not the other way around.