# Custom Buffered Input Stream for on-the-fly reading/pull

Tags: java, io, stream

I need to pass an InputStream to an object which reads data which I previously stored into a File. I'm assessing a more efficient approach than storing eveything into a File and then passing the FileInputStream. I'd like to do it on the fly.

May someone appoint me the correct approach to do that?

The idea would be passing a Custom InputStream which innerly calls every line I was going to store in the file. I guess I need buffering. I discard storing everything in a String and then  build an InputStream on it, as we are in the same situation, waiting to output all the lines before rereading them again.

Comment: your question is unclear..! Show us your attempt!

Comment: I don't want the solution, just understanding what is the best approach to do that, maybe I am forgetting some magical class in io package or something, or some apprach is strongly discouraged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a stream for this. It's the [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html). You'll need to have one thread write to the `PipedOutputStream`, and pass the `PipedInputStream` to the object that will be reading in another thread.

Comment: Nice That is exactly what I was looking for! I'll let the question open in case it could exist an even higher level solution, but I doubt it, so probably I will accept this one in a while!

Comment: Damn, I found the SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/java-converting-from-outputstream-to-inputstream