# InputStream to OutputStream

Tags: java, stream

I have to a class that generates an Excel file, class takes an output stream, intended for a `FileOutputWriter`.
However I need to upload the file to S3 later, so saving it to a file would be an unnecessary step.
To upload a file to S3 do I need it as an input stream.

I have therefore been looking for a way to convert an output stream to an input stream or transfer the data to an input stream.

I have tried `PipeOutputStream`, but `xlsFile.write(outstr);` just blocks forever when using a `PipedOutputStream`, using a `FileOutputStream` will it work fine and write the file.

```
PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
try (OutputStream outstr = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream)) {
    xlsFile.write(outstr);
    outstr.flush();
    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: Because you're doing it in a single thread.

Comment: I imagine you'd be able to use the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream

Comment: `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream` are supposed to be processed in different threads. Processing them in a single threads causes the thread to block itself. See an example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23874232/166589

Comment: Since this only works when the entire contents has been buffered, just write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and return a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapping the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

[JDK 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) has added [`InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream out)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) for this functionality, though JDK 9 is not yet released. Early releases are available [here](http://jdk.java.net/9/).