# JDK8+ java.util.Base64 wrap() complementary methods

Tags: java, java-8, base64, stream-processing

Since JDK8, mature java.util.Base64 APIs have been added.

The only methods to stream process InputStream(s) and OutputStream(s) are, respectively:

- Base64.get*Decoder().wrap(is)
- Base64.get*Encoder().wrap(os).

How can I encode an InputStream or decode and OuputStream using **only** Java APIs in an **efficient** way?

Is there a reason those methods have not been added to Java APIs?

This functionality is present, for example, in **net.iharder.base64**, but I was migrating to Java APIs in order to remove that dependency.

Comment: I suppose, this has been considered rarely needed. Can you describe your actual use case?

Comment: Well, if the API only wants to decode InputStreams and encode OutputStreams you have to "convert" them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/how-to-convert-outputstream-to-inputstream